# UnicodeDecodeError: While reading a csv file using .csvreader

Tags: pandas, csv, python-3.6

Here's my code:

```
import csv
path = "/home/Downloads/sample_email.csv"
with open(path) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

The error is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-d89ea200a227> in <module>
      3 with open(path) as csvfile:
      4     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
----> 5     for i in reader:
      6          print(i['first_name'], i['last_name'])

/usr/lib/python3.6/csv.py in __next__(self)
    109         if self.line_num == 0:
    110             # Used only for its side effect.
--> 111             self.fieldnames
    112         row = next(self.reader)
    113         self.line_num = self.reader.line_num

/usr/lib/python3.6/csv.py in fieldnames(self)
     96         if self._fieldnames is None:
     97             try:
---> 98                 self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
     99             except StopIteration:
    100                 pass

/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 596: invalid start byte
```

When i want to convert this file to df, i have to use :

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=',', engine = 'python')
```

Any help?

My aim is , extract the data, and a create a email template. Any guide about this matter is also appriciated.